# Get genres of music from listening history

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy, spotify-app

I have the following csv file [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h26Rz.png) which contains the features of the songs that have been listened to by a spotify user. The features I extracted with the following code block [2]. I would now like to add the information relating to the genre of the song, what can I do? Or is there a way to go back to the genre of the song starting from the bpm?

[image]

[2]

```
def get_id(track_name: str,artist:str, token: str) -> str:
    headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': f'Bearer ' + token,
    }
    track_artist = track_name+ " " + artist
    params = [
    ('q',track_artist ),#q is the search query parameter
    ('type', 'track'),
    ]
    try:
        response = requests.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search', 
                    headers = headers, params = params, timeout = 10)
        json = response.json()
        first_result = json['tracks']['items'][0]
        track_id = first_result['id']
        return track_id
    except:
        return None

# Get track_id for streaming history    
spotify_data["track_id"] = spotify_data.apply(lambda x: get_id(x["track_name"],
                                                               x["artist_name"],
                                                                 token),axis=1)
# get track's feature
my_feature = pd.DataFrame(columns=["song_id","energy", "liveness","tempo","speechiness",
                                "acousticness","instrumentalness","danceability",
                                "duration_ms","loudness","valence",
                                "mode","key","genre"])
```

In case you need it I can show you all the code I use, I didn't do it just to avoid pasting useless code.

Comment: If you don't have the genre in your data, well, you just don't have it. Try to get better data. The BPM won't be much help...

Comment: Do you have any tips or ways to get better data? Any alternative that allows you to exploit other columns to obtain musical genres? I am really without ideas I have tried them all, I have looked around but I do not find anything interesting for my case

Comment: For every genre on Spotify there are at least 2 playlists: _The Sound of [genre]_ and _Intro to [genre]_. You can find all genres and their playlists [here][1]. You can try to get audio features of those playlists of the genres you are interested in and calculate the averages. (I can guess Rock music has a higher instrumentalness than House music.)


  [1]: https://everynoise.com/everynoise1d.cgi?scope=all

Comment: Using Spotify APIs you can still get the genre by artist:
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/get-an-artist